# iDangerous swiper reverse pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js, idangero

I am trying to create iDangerous swiper with custom pagination. By default, the swiper's pagination goes from 1 to 10. Could someone here help me to reverse the order from 10 to 1?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (index + 1) + '</span>';
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Swiper demo</title>
  <!-- Link Swiper's CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Swiper -->
  <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

  <!-- Swiper JS -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
  <script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        renderBullet: function (index, className) {
          const totalEl = (document.getElementsByClassName("swiper-slide")).length;
          return '<span class="' + className + '">' + (-1*(index - totalEl)) + '</span>';
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```